# Apache - only uses 8 characters of password? MD5?

Tags: apache

I've read around looking for solutions to this problem, which has led to even more confusion.

My problem is that Apache will only take the first 8 characters of the password, and will ignore the rest. For purposes security, this isn't ideal and I need a solution whereby I can use longer passwords. I know this is default behaviour.

I created the .htpasswd file using htpasswd with the -c flag. I read that using -m for MD5 will not work while I'm using a .htaccess file? Is that correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: is doing the above any different from using -m on the command line?

Comment: I cannot tell for certain. I think it should be the same. I just found the above tool convenient.